# Swift Table View Cell Value Failed to display vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am new to swift . I am creating table view cell programatically with the sub title . I defined the two label and two function to get the value form API and display it into label control but the problem is the values of label are displayed into correct position . I want to display the title and then below the title is sub title values . Here is the screen shot .[image: screenshot]

Here is the code table view cell.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.rovers.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryCell.identifier , for: indexPath) as? StoryCell
        else{ return UITableViewCell()}
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        
        let title = viewModel.getTitle(by: row)
        cell.configureCell(title:title)
        
        let Id = viewModel.getId(by: row)
        cell.configureCell(Id: Id)
        return cell
    }
    
   
}
```

Here is code for configure the label .

```
import UIKit

class StoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "StoryCell"
    
    private lazy var storyTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()
    
    
    private lazy var storyIdLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpUI()
        setUpUIID()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureCell(title: String) {
        storyTitleLabel.text = "Status :\(title)"
    }
    
    func configureCell(Id: Int) {
        storyIdLabel.text = "Id: \(String(Id))"
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    private func setUpUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(storyTitleLabel)
        
        // constraints
        let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        storyTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        storyTitleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        storyTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        storyTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
       
    }
    
    
   private func setUpUIID() {
        contentView.addSubview(storyIdLabel)
        
        // constraints
        let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        storyIdLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        storyIdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        storyIdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        storyIdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in your code check below. Now it should be fine.

```
private func setUpUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(storyTitleLabel)
    
    // constraints
    let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    storyTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
    storyTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    storyTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
}

private func setUpUIID() {
    contentView.addSubview(storyIdLabel)
    let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    storyIdLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storyTitleLabel.topAnchor).constant = 5
    storyIdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    storyIdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    storyIdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```